# Statistical test for two samples and unreplicated blocked data

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I used the Friedman test with more than two samples and unreplicated blocked data.

However, in my situation, I have only two samples and unreplicated blocked data.

What statistical test you think would be suitable for such samples. The column is for regression method and rows are for different data sets. SAD =sum absolute deviations. I do not care about normality.

[image]

Comment: What is the hypothesis you want to test? If it is about agreement, maybe add the tag [tag:agreement-statistics].  And also, add the example data as text, so it is readable ...

Answer (score 0):

It isn`t clear what your hypothesis is, you could clarify that by editing your post, it could possible be about agreement? But anyhow, I would start by plotting the data, and since this is paired data a Tukey mean-difference plot could be of use (also called Bland-Altman plot).

I use logs for the x scale of means:

[image]

Comment: I want to investigate and check if there is a significant difference between algorithm BR and IRLS (first and second column).

Comment: The plots shows an obvious outlier. Maybe start with investigating that! The outlier must be *PPPTS. What is that?